# Conjectures or Results?

Tags: journals, conjectures

There is a paper (not accepted for publication yet) that contains several conjectures. Some of these conjectures were proven recently.

The referee of the original paper requires to substitute the proven "Conjectures" with the "Results". However, there are several papers that cite these conjectures, so I feel it would be wrong to rename them.

What is the best (or standard) way to indicate in the original paper that the conjectures were proven in the subsequent papers? Are there any good examples of doing that?

Comment: With the amount of time between preprint posting and final journal publishing being often considerable, this is common (or at least not uncommon) and personally I think it's fine to state the conjectures as Conjectures (while of course explaining that they have subsequently been proven).

Comment: I would indicate it in footnotes.

Comment: My opinion is that this question is opinion-based. More seriously, my personal viewpoint is that the title must be maximally informative. If you say "Conjectures" in the title, this will be misleading if the conjectures are resolved already. And if you say "Results", this will conceal the fact that the paper is mostly about the conjectures which have been later resolved. Is not it possible to avoid both words "Conjectures" and "Results" in the title and just say something like "About those or these properties of this or that"?

Comment: I think it's a good idea not to be rigid, and rename conjectures as results/theorems, to say "Fermat-Wiles theorem" rather than "Fermat conjecture", etc.

Comment: Check out page 7 of the latest version of https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2632 to see a pretty extreme example of discussion of "subsequent developments" since the first posting of a paper.

Comment: @auniket : Some journals don't allow footnotes. I think the _American Mathematical Monthly_ is one of those (although that's probably not the sort of journal you have in mind). I have the impression that the _Pacific Journal of Mathematics_ is extremely rigidly fastidious about compliance with its extensive style requirements (so I suspect many others are as well) (but I don't know how PJM feels about footnotes).

Comment: I wonder whether the conventional name of the Riemann Hypothesis will change if a proof is published? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Given that Poincare's conjecture and Fermat's last theorem are still (at least most commonly) called the way they were prior to their proof, I suspect Riemann hypothesis will have similar fate.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Since it's called the Riemann *Hypothesis*, I suspect the name won't change. In practice, RH is most frequently invoked as a hypothesis in the literal sense of one of the hypotheses of some other theorem. If RH is proved, that doesn't make it wrong to call it a hypothesis (redundant, maybe, but not wrong).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The standard way is to leave the conjectures as they are, and add a remark, or a footnote, saying that "after this paper was written (or after it was submitted for publication) this conjecture was proved"
and give a reference.